# PHP loop through Products

Tags: php, loops

I hope I'm at the right place and that I did not copy too much of my code below - The code below will produce a report displaying ALL existing products from database - What I'm trying to achieve its to display just specific product (lets call them gid 1 and 2).

What I cannot wrap my head around ( maybe because I'm a network guy): I don't want to display certain product group, when I modify the SQL query, I'm able to remove the data ( amount$) but I want the entire Product category not to be display.

My question: is it more in the 'loop through product' that I need to change the code or in my SQL  query ( I doubt) - and if you could tell me how to proceed.

Thank you to help me - I have close to 0 hours experience with PHP.

```
<?php

if (!defined("WHMCS"))
    die("This file cannot be accessed directly");

$pmonth = str_pad((int)$month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

$reportdata["title"] = "Immobilier DD - Income by Product for ".$months[(int)$month]." ".$year;
$reportdata["description"] = "This report provides a breakdown per product/service of invoices paid in a given month. Please note this excludes overpayments & other payments made to deposit funds (credit), and includes invoices paid from credit added in previous months, and thus may not match the income total for the month.";
$reportdata["currencyselections"] = true;

$reportdata["tableheadings"] = array("Product Name","Units Sold","Value");

$products = $addons = array();

# Loop Through Products
$result = full_query("SELECT tblhosting.packageid,COUNT(*),SUM(tblinvoiceitems.amount) FROM tblinvoiceitems INNER JOIN tblinvoices ON tblinvoices.id=tblinvoiceitems.invoiceid INNER JOIN tblhosting ON tblhosting.id=tblinvoiceitems.relid INNER JOIN tblclients ON tblclients.id=tblinvoices.userid  WHERE tblinvoices.datepaid LIKE '".(int)$year."-".$pmonth."-%' AND (tblinvoiceitems.type='Hosting' OR tblinvoiceitems.type='Setup' OR tblinvoiceitems.type LIKE 'ProrataProduct%') AND currency=".(int)$currencyid."  GROUP BY tblhosting.packageid");
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $products[$data[0]] = array("amount" => $data[2],"unitssold" => $data[1]);
}


# Loop Through Product Discounts
$result = full_query("SELECT tblhosting.packageid,COUNT(*),SUM(tblinvoiceitems.amount) FROM tblinvoiceitems INNER JOIN tblinvoices ON tblinvoices.id=tblinvoiceitems.invoiceid INNER JOIN tblhosting ON tblhosting.id=tblinvoiceitems.relid INNER JOIN tblclients ON tblclients.id=tblinvoices.userid WHERE tblinvoices.datepaid LIKE '".(int)$year."-".$pmonth."-%' AND tblinvoiceitems.type='PromoHosting' AND currency=".(int)$currencyid." GROUP BY tblhosting.packageid");
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $products[$data[0]]["amount"] += $data[2];
}

# Loop Through Addons
$result = full_query("SELECT tblhostingaddons.addonid,COUNT(*),SUM(tblinvoiceitems.amount) FROM tblinvoiceitems INNER JOIN tblinvoices ON tblinvoices.id=tblinvoiceitems.invoiceid INNER JOIN tblhostingaddons ON tblhostingaddons.id=tblinvoiceitems.relid INNER JOIN tblclients ON tblclients.id=tblinvoices.userid WHERE tblinvoices.datepaid LIKE '".(int)$year."-".$pmonth."-%' AND tblinvoiceitems.type='Addon' AND currency=".(int)$currencyid." GROUP BY tblhostingaddons.addonid");
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $addons[$data[0]] = array("amount" => $data[2],"unitssold" => $data[1]);
}

$total = 0;
$itemtotal = 0;
$firstdone = false;
$result = select_query("tblproducts","tblproducts.id,tblproducts.name,tblproductgroups.name AS groupname","","tblproductgroups`.`order` ASC,`tblproducts`.`order` ASC,`name","ASC","","tblproductgroups ON tblproducts.gid=tblproductgroups.id");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $pid = $data["id"];
    $group = $data["groupname"];
    $prodname = $data["name"];

    if ($group!=$prevgroup) {
        $total += $itemtotal;
        if ($firstdone) {
            $reportdata["tablevalues"][] = array('','<strong>Sub-Total</strong>','<strong>'.formatCurrency($itemtotal).'</strong>');
            $chartdata['rows'][] = array('c'=>array(array('v'=>$prevgroup),array('v'=>$itemtotal,'f'=>formatCurrency($itemtotal))));
        }
        $reportdata["tablevalues"][] = array("**<strong>$group</strong>");
        $itemtotal = 0;
    }

    $amount = $products[$pid]["amount"];
    $number = $products[$pid]["unitssold"];

    $itemtotal += $amount;

    if (!$amount) $amount="0.00";
    if (!$number) $number="0";
    $amount = formatCurrency($amount);

    $reportdata["tablevalues"][] = array($prodname,$number,$amount);

    $prevgroup = $group;
    $firstdone = true;

}

$total += $itemtotal;
$reportdata["tablevalues"][] = array('','<strong>Sub-Total</strong>','<strong>'.formatCurrency($itemtotal).'</strong>');
$chartdata['rows'][] = array('c'=>array(array('v'=>$group),array('v'=>$itemtotal,'f'=>formatCurrency($itemtotal))));

$reportdata["tablevalues"][] = array("**<strong>Addons</strong>");

$itemtotal = 0;
$result = select_query("tbladdons","id,name","","name","ASC");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $addonid = $data["id"];
    $prodname = $data["name"];

    $amount = $addons[$addonid]["amount"];
    $number = $addons[$addonid]["unitssold"];

    $itemtotal += $amount;

    if (!$amount) $amount="0.00";
    if (!$number) $number="0";
    $amount = formatCurrency($amount);

    $reportdata["tablevalues"][] = array($prodname,$number,$amount);

    $prevgroup = $group;

}

$itemtotal += $addons[0]["amount"];
$number = $addons[0]["unitssold"];
$amount = $addons[0]["amount"];
if (!$amount) $amount="0.00";
if (!$number) $number="0";
$reportdata["tablevalues"][] = array('Miscellaneous Custom Addons',$number,formatCurrency($amount));

$total += $itemtotal;
$reportdata["tablevalues"][] = array('','<strong>Sub-Total</strong>','<strong>'.formatCurrency($itemtotal).'</strong>');
$chartdata['rows'][] = array('c'=>array(array('v'=>"Addons"),array('v'=>$itemtotal,'f'=>formatCurrency($itemtotal))));

$itemtotal = 0;
$reportdata["tablevalues"][] = array("**<strong>Miscellaneous</strong>");

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(tblinvoiceitems.amount)
        FROM tblinvoiceitems
        INNER JOIN tblinvoices ON tblinvoices.id=tblinvoiceitems.invoiceid 
        INNER JOIN tblclients ON tblclients.id=tblinvoices.userid
        WHERE tblinvoices.datepaid LIKE '" . (int)$year . "-" . $pmonth . "-%' AND tblinvoiceitems.type='Item' AND currency=" . (int)$currencyid;
$result = full_query($sql);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$itemtotal += $data[1];
$number = $data[0];
$amount = $data[1];
if (!$amount) $amount="0.00";
if (!$number) $number="0";
$reportdata["tablevalues"][] = array('Billable Items',$number,formatCurrency($amount));

$result = full_query("SELECT COUNT(*),SUM(tblinvoiceitems.amount) FROM tblinvoiceitems INNER JOIN tblinvoices ON tblinvoices.id=tblinvoiceitems.invoiceid INNER JOIN tblclients ON tblclients.id=tblinvoices.userid WHERE tblinvoices.datepaid LIKE '".(int)$year."-".$pmonth."-%' AND tblinvoiceitems.type='' AND currency='$currencyid'");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$itemtotal += $data[1];
$reportdata["tablevalues"][] = array('Custom Invoice Line Items',$data[0],formatCurrency($data[1]));

$total += $itemtotal;
$reportdata["tablevalues"][] = array('','<strong>Sub-Total</strong>','<strong>'.formatCurrency($itemtotal).'</strong>');
$chartdata['rows'][] = array('c'=>array(array('v'=>"Miscellaneous"),array('v'=>$itemtotal,'f'=>formatCurrency($itemtotal))));

$total = formatCurrency($total);

$chartdata['cols'][] = array('label'=>'Days Range','type'=>'string');
$chartdata['cols'][] = array('label'=>'Value','type'=>'number');

$args = array();
$args['legendpos'] = 'right';

$reportdata["footertext"] = $chart->drawChart('Pie',$chartdata,$args,'300px');

$reportdata["monthspagination"] = true;
```

Comment: sorry, this is too much code ... But from your description I'd say it _is_ a sql question. If you only need a certain group then you should filter there already.

Comment: side note: `mysql_*` functions are old, unsecure, deprecated and _removed_ in php7. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead!